# width 100% on checkboxes makes it center aligned. How can I counter this?

Tags: html, css, input, width

I am setting all inputs to a 100% width via CSS. However, checkboxes are center aligned for some reason.
Anyway to counter this?
I don't want to have to use attribute selection via css since they're not fully supported.

Comment: What result are you actually trying to achieve? For operating systems that render checkboxes at a fixed size, what should width:100% as far as you're concerned?

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the width back to auto (`width: auto`).

If you don't want to use attribute selectors, then you must find another selector that matches the checkboxes. This may well involve adding additional markup (such as a class).

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your checkbox in another element:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="check-value">Human readable value
</div>
```

In CSS:

```
.checkbox {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: tried text-align. It doesn't do anything.
The reason it is centered is because of width being 100%

Comment: I have changed my answer and I have tested my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
input.checkbox 
{ 
    text-align: left; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```